# Woocommerce overridden not work after Administrator logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woothemes, woocommerce-theming

I've copied the folder `plugin/woocommerce/template` to `theme/mytheme/woocommerce`and designed a new template and just checked `Woocommerce/System Status` to make sure overridden is worked.

The template works fine but when the user or the admin logged in , the overridden code does not work and the template defaults to `plugin/woocommerce/template` and shows the default template

the problem happened for this particular pages:

> - **Product-single.php**
> - **taxonomy-product_cat.php**
> - **archive-product.php**

And this problem happen just when Administrator logged in

How can this problem be addressed?

I Also Disable All plugin (except `woocommerce`), copy original `woocommerce` template file to `twentysixteen Template` and modify that.

But The Problem not Solved Anyway!

**I use woocommerce 2.5.5 And Wordpress  4.4.2**

Comment: Which file in particular are you trying to add a template for?

Comment: @AndrewM all of the woocommerce template file, for example `single-product.php` or `cart.php` back to defaults

Comment: Have you checked in your **backend menu** > **WooCommerce** > **System status** page, in the section named **Templates** (located at the end), you have the list of all **active** overrides templates. If for example, you see in there `single-product.php`, `cart.php` and some others templates, that mean that they **are really active**. If you don't see anything (empty, no list items), it is certainly a path problem: you just have to copy the "templates" folder (located in the woocommerce plugin folder) to your theme folder. Then you have to rename it "woocommerce".

Comment: @Louis yes, i do it. and see all overridden page on there.

Comment: Just to clarify, you say that the problem happen with logged user roles "user" and "administrator". You certainly mean "customer" and "administrator", right?

Comment: Ok, next lasts things: This kind of problem can come also when template overrides is in debug mode: WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools -> Template debug mode "on". Also have you checked if the problem don't come from  "woocommerce.php" file located in your theme folder.

Comment: Last try :) -  When you updated to the newest version of woocommerce, you may have to "reinstall" the woocommerce pages because the old system did not use the `wc_get_page_id()` function, which looks for the shop page: WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools ->"Install WooCommerce Pages". This will not override your existing pages.

Comment: Is this solved or it remain with the same problem? Another trick from very active [helgatheviking](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking) is to use the default wordpress theme to see if the issue don't come from your theme.

Comment: I hope in your case after updating "Template Debug Mode" was enabled. That's why you can not override the templates anymore.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry reply too late :( i template in debug mode. it's not updating version , clean install last version. problem not solved!

Comment: @hemnathmouli sorry reply to late. template in debug mode. problem not solved yet

Comment: Have you added [WooCommerce support](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#section-3) to your theme?

Answer (score 0):

try disable debug mode from wp-config.php

```
define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false );
```